# Subquery in FROM clause failing in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a SELECT statement for pulling parent contact info from the address table of a student database. I need to define the query to return parent info only for current students (student_group='Student'), however the query ignores this and returns info for all student groups (i.e. 'Graduate', 'Withdrawn', etc.). Can you see what I've done wrong here? Thank you.

```
        SELECT DISTINCT
        --Name 1 in P1 household
        s.id
        ,a.name1_web_user_id as contact_1_id
        ,a.name1_full_name as contact_1_name
        ,case 'Name1:Mobile' 
            when a.Other_No_Type_1 then a.Other_No_1
            when a.Other_No_Type_2 then a.Other_No_2
            when a.Other_No_Type_3 then a.Other_No_3
            when a.Other_No_Type_4 then a.Other_No_4
            end as contact_1_mobile
        ,a.email as contact_1_email
       
        --Name 2 in P1 household
        ,a.name2_web_user_id as contact_2_id
        ,a.name2_full_name as contact_2_name
        ,case 'Name2:Mobile' 
            when a.Other_No_Type_1 then a.Other_No_1
            when a.Other_No_Type_2 then a.Other_No_2
            when a.Other_No_Type_3 then a.Other_No_3
            when a.Other_No_Type_4 then a.Other_No_4
            end as contact_2_mobile
        ,a.email_2 as contact_2_email
            
        --Name 1 in P2 household
        ,s.id
        ,b.name1_web_user_id as contact_3_id
        ,b.name1_full_name as contact_3_name
        ,case 'Name1:Mobile' 
            when b.Other_No_Type_1 then b.Other_No_1
            when b.Other_No_Type_2 then b.Other_No_2
            when b.Other_No_Type_3 then b.Other_No_3
            when b.Other_No_Type_4 then b.Other_No_4
            end as contact_3_mobile
        ,b.email as contact_3_email
        
        --Name 2 in P2 household
        ,b.name2_web_user_id as contact_4_id
        ,b.name2_full_name as contact_4_name
        ,case 'Name2:Mobile' 
            when b.Other_No_Type_1 then b.Other_No_1
            when b.Other_No_Type_2 then b.Other_No_2
            when b.Other_No_Type_3 then b.Other_No_3
            when b.Other_No_Type_4 then b.Other_No_4
            end as contact_4_mobile
        ,b.email_2 as contact_4_email
            
FROM rg_student s
    left outer join rg_addr a on s.id=a.id
    AND  a.addr_code='P1' AND a.rg_active = 'Y' 
    AND s.id in(SELECT id from rg_student where student_group='Student')
        left outer join rg_addr b on s.id=b.id
        AND  a.addr_code='P2' AND b.rg_active = 'Y' 
        AND s.id in(SELECT id from rg_student where student_group='Student')
```

I simplified the FROM clause, and in the process lost the output of contact_3 and contact_4 data. Here's what I have now:

```
FROM rg_student s
    left outer join rg_addr a on s.id=a.id
        and  a.addr_code='P1' AND a.rg_active = 'Y' 
                
     left outer join rg_addr b on s.id=b.id           
        and  a.addr_code='P2' AND b.rg_active = 'Y' 
                                
    WHERE s.student_group = 'Student'
```

Comment: Why are you using `IN` at all? If the student rows have the information whether the student is a current student, use a simple `WHERE` clause: `select * from rg_stdent where student_group='Student' and rg_active = 'Y'`.

Comment: `s.id=a.id`? Are you sure? Why should a student D equal an address ID? Does your student table have an address_id or the address table a student_id maybe?

Comment: Yes, the IDs are the same, because the address table I'm referencing is a view of combined student data and address data.

Comment: If this is already a view, why must you join then with the student table? Doesn't it contain all the information needed? And if it doesn't, why do you use it? Why not join to the address *table* then instead? (And in such a view containing both student and address information, you should not call the student ID `id`, but `student_id` or the like to make it clear whether it's the student ID or the address ID or still some other ID.)

Comment: Hi Thorsten, it's not my database, but the database behind our student information software, and it contains a couple of hundred tables and views. Using that particular address view lets me bypass a couple of other joins. I agree with you about the naming. Meanwhile, I'm in a position where I need to get data out of it to create files for third-party vendors to use in providing us service we need.

Comment: Okay. The answer remains the same. Use `WHERE` on the student table, use `ON` for the address joins. I've posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to select all current students, so select from the student table and use `WHERE´ to only select current students.

You want to join with addresses, so join and specify the join conditions in the `ON` clause.

```
select
  ...
FROM rg_student s
LEFT JOIN rg_addr p1 ON p1.id = s.id AND p1.addr_code = 'P1' AND p1.rg_active = 'Y' 
LEFT JOIN rg_addr p2 ON p2.id = s.id AND p2.addr_code = 'P2' AND p2.rg_active = 'Y' 
WHERE s.student_group = 'Student';
```

Comment: Thank you, Thorsten. Every time I spend 12 hours trying to figure out and find out how to get what I need, I do learn something.

Answer (score 2):

You are not using where clause which means every condition is part of the join statement change your query to something like this

```
FROM rg_student s
        left outer join rg_addr a on s.id=a.id
        left outer join rg_addr b on s.id=b.id
        where a.addr_code in ('P2', 'P1') AND b.rg_active = 'Y' 
                 AND s.id in(SELECT id from rg_student where s.student_group='Student')  AND a.rg_active = 'Y'
```

Comment: Thanks, mohd. I've learned that using WHERE doesn't work in this query. I've posted the entire query to provide more information.

Comment: Is it still not working ? Provide the sample data as well.

Comment: Paul, if I switch to WHERE, I get :ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Comment: @mohd atif: The idea is correct, a `WHERE` clause is needed. But joins need an `ON` clause still. Replacing the two `ON` with `WHERE` only results in a syntax error hence.

Comment: I see. I have used two where clause in the query which is wrong.Edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

As has been said, you've put your condition in the wrong place.

You're also doing far too much work.

Get rid of both instances of this.   They're pointless.

```
s.id in(SELECT id from rg_student where student_group='Student')
```

Once you've done that, add

```
WHERE s.student_group = 'Student'
```

To the bottom of your query.

This shouldn't be part of a LEFT JOIN condition (which returns whether things are met or not) and it shouldn't have to do a sub select on itself when the value you're discriminating on is already in your rg_student table.

Comment: Thank you, Paul, that worked. This query began simply, grew unreasonably in the wee hours of the morning, and has now been pared down to be functional. Finally. I'm learning...

Comment: Argh, no. I changed the FROM and lost all the output for contact_3 and contact_4 columns...

Comment: Thanks again, Paul. If I knew more than I do, I'm sure this would have been all the info I needed.